# run bower install for target bower.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

Assume that my working directory is `c:\foo\` during the script execution. I would like run bower from there for `c:\foo\bar\bower.json` file. This is available on npm by running `npm install --prefix c:\foo\bar`.

Is there any equivalent command in bower?

Comment: Does that actually work in `npm`? I thought `--prefix` was for the target, not the manifest.

Comment: @Mathletics yes, right. It's the directory. not the package.json file. updated the question.

Comment: where do you want the packages installed? `\foo\bower_components` or `\foo\bar\bower_components`?

Comment: @Mathletics `\foo\bar\bower_components`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `.bowerrc` file to `c:\foo\` with the following contents:

```
{
   "cwd": "bar
}
```

this will set the working directory for Bower to `c:\foo\bar\`.